# SQL Group By Substring

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have a date column in my table:

```
Date
1/1/2005
1/2/2005
1/1/2006
1/1/2007
1/1/2007
```

And I want to group specifically by year. How would I do that?

I know how to search for a specific year `LIKE "%2005"` but I'm not sure if that's helpful in this scenario

Comment: "And I want to group specifically by year. How would I do that?" `GROUP BY YEAR(..)` ?? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year.. First you need to store normal MySQL datatimes like 2005-01-01

Comment: Set your `Date` become `to_date` ? more like `select to_date(date, %Y)` and do group by  `Date`

Comment: What is `to_date`? @dwir182 this is not Oracle database..

Comment: sorry wrong.. my bad.. date_format

Comment: [if you want to test it but get closed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df8f014dc54ad790791eebe57e86345d)